Overriding starting number of endnote without effect
I expected the first note would be labeled 11, not 1. What is the right way to do it?
tex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setenotez{list-name = {Notes}}

\setcounter{endnote}{10}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-2] See notes~\ref{note:a} and \ref{note:b}.

\endnote[1]{\lipsum[2][1]}\label{note:a}
\endnote[2]{\lipsum[3][1] See note~\ref{note:c}.}\label{note:b}
\endnote[3]{\lipsum[4][1]}\label{note:c}

\printendnotes

\end{document}

log:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.4.13)  2 MAY 2024 16:41
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**debug.tex
(./debug.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enotez/enotez.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2024-03-14 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-03-14 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count196
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2024-03-14 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2024-03-14 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate.st
y
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate-20
23-10-10.sty
Package: xtemplate 2023-10-10 L3 Experimental prototype document functions
\l__xtemplate_tmp_dim=\dimen141
\l__xtemplate_tmp_int=\count197
\l__xtemplate_tmp_muskip=\muskip16
\l__xtemplate_tmp_skip=\skip50
))
Package: enotez 2022/01/04 v0.10d Endnotes for LaTeX2e
\l__enotez_list_preamble_skip=\skip51
\l__enotez_list_postamble_skip=\skip52
\g__enotez_endnote_id_int=\count198
\g__enotez_endnote_mark_int=\count199
\c@endnote=\count266
\g__enotez_list_printed_int=\count267
\l__enotez_tmpa_int=\count268

Package xtemplate Info: Declaring object type 'enotez-list' taking 1
(xtemplate)             argument(s) on line 473.

\l__enotez_list_notes_sep_dim=\dimen142

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations.sty
Package: translations 2022/02/05 v1.12 internationalization of LaTeX2e packages
 (CN)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count269
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
Package: lipsum 2021-09-20 v2.7 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\g__lipsum_par_int=\count270
\l__lipsum_a_int=\count271
\l__lipsum_b_int=\count272

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex))
Package translations Info: No language package found. I am going to use `englis
h' as default language. on input line 12.

(./debug.aux)
\openout1 = `debug.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations-basic-d
ictionary-english.trsl
File: translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl (english translation file `tra
nslations-basic-dictionary')
)
Package translations Info: loading dictionary `translations-basic-dictionary' f
or `english'. on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 16.
 [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./debu
g.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3070 strings out of 474104
 75979 string characters out of 5743473
 1927493 words of memory out of 5000000
 25463 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558973 words of font info for 39 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 71i,5n,79p,222b,177s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb
></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></us
r/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb>
Output written on debug.pdf (1 page, 46165 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 28 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 16 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

output:


If you want the endnotes to follow the counter, why are you manually setting the mark with \endnote[1], \endnote[2], etc.? When you do that, you not only override the counter's value, but (if I recall correctly...) this results in \refstepcounter not being called for the note. Just don't do it:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setenotez{list-name = {Notes}}

\setcounter{endnote}{10}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-2] See notes~\ref{note:a} and \ref{note:b}.

\endnote{\lipsum[2][1]}\label{note:a}
\endnote{\lipsum[3][1] See note~\ref{note:c}.}\label{note:b}
\endnote{\lipsum[4][1]}\label{note:c}

\printendnotes

\end{document}



"why are you manually setting the mark with \endnote[1], \endonte[2], etc." Oversight of mine.
